# Как правильно - РУГАТЕЛЬНОЕ или РУГАТЕЛЬСКОЕ слово?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

"Оформляла" дополнение к ответу и столкнулась с дилеммой.

"Потому что дурак - не  **ругательское**  слово..."
 "Ты слышала от Сильвии хоть одно  **ругательное**  слово или оскорбление в   чей-то адрес?"
 Как правильно?

Comment: Раз уж вопросы были разделены, возможно, теперь стоит принять какой-либо ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: **ругательное (плохое, содержащее ругань) слово.**

В настоящее время  слово "ругательский" применяется редко, но можно ли считать, что "ругательский" ― это **только народно-разговорный вариант** для прилагательного "ругательный"?

Вообще говоря, суффикс СК обозначает **общее отношение** к предмету, а суффикс Н **качественно** характеризует предмет, поэтому частотность применения ожидаемо  выше у прилагательного "ругательный" (содержащий ругань).

В то же время встречаются ситуации, когда "ругательный" плохо подходит по смыслу, например: Во всех углах, под хлестанье воды, гремел ее **ругательский голос**. [А. Г. Малышкин. Люди из захолустья (1938)].

Также интересно, что **есть наречие "ругательски", но нет наречия "ругательно".**

Отметим, что Ломоносов пользовался словом "ругательский":   Наконец ругательский титул: «благий учитель!»[М. В. Ломоносов. Письмо И. И. Шувалову (1753)]

Answer (score 4):

Оба слова фиксируются словарями, но ["ругательский"](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&all=x) сопровождает помета "народно-разговорное". Нормативным считается "ругательный".

> РУГАТЕЛЬСКИЙ. *Нар.-разг.* =Ругательный. *Р-ие речи. Р-ая переписка.*
>
> РУГАТЕЛЬНЫЙ. Являющийся руганью, содержащий в себе ругань. *Р-ые
>   слова. Р-ая рецензия* (резко критикующая).

А [словарь Ушакова](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1012258) (которому сто лет в обед) считает эти слова безоговорочными синонимами.

> РУГА́ТЕЛЬНЫЙ. Содержащий ругань. *Ругательные слова. Ругательное
>   письмо.* || Отрицательный, порицающий (разг.). *Ругательный отзыв.*
>
> РУГА́ТЕЛЬСКИЙ. Очень ругательный. Ругательски *(нареч.)* ругать
>   (сильно ругать). *«Начинают на всех перекрестках ругательски меня
>   ругать».* Салтыков-Щедрин.

[Толковый словарь Ефремовой](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/239388) (2000) снова даёт помету "разговорное":

руга́тельский

прил. разг.

1.
соотн. с сущ. ругательство, связанный с ним

2.
Свойственный ругательству, характерный для него.

3.
Содержащий ругательство, очень ругательный.

Answer (score 1):

Ну в общем-то все сошлись, что **ругательный** - основная форма. **Ругательский** - форма разговорная, или как её определяет Кузнецов - народно-разговорная. О просторечности речь не идет, поэтому отвергать сходу вариант ругательский я бы не стал.

В отношении примера из Булгакова. 
"Это роль ругательная" - само по себе сомнений не вызывает.

> РУГАТЕЛЬНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -лен, -льна, -льно. Являющийся руганью,
>   содержащий в себе ругань. Р-ые слова. Р-ая рецензия (резко
>   критикующая).

http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Другое дело, что в устах Бунши, да еще с учетом абсурдности всего контекста, оно приобретает ярко выраженный комический оттенок. Но это уже заслуга Булгакова.

Замена на "ругательский" здесь вполне возможна (Бунша вообще не страдает высоким стилем), но необходимости в том нет никакой.

Answer (score 0):

По значению эти слова ничем не отличаются. Есть только стилистическая разница.

РУГАТЕЛЬСКИЙ, -ая, -ое. ***Нар.-разг. =Ругательный***. Р-ие речи. Р-ая переписка. <Ругательски, нареч. Ругать р. (ругательными словами). Усилит.

Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.
Первое издание: СПб.: Норинт, 1998.